# Set default product image via REST API

Tags: api, product-images, rest-api, ce-1.9.1.0

I'm using Magento REST API to create products and upload images. No problems so far, but i can't find a way to set an image as the default image to be displayed on the store using the API.

Is there a way to do so without modifying magento?

I'm using Magento CE 1.9.1.0

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried setting its position to 0?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to set the image as "base", "small", "thumbnail" or "swatch".

```
"product" => {
        "sku" => "test",
        "name" =>  "Test Product",
        "attribute_set_id" =>  4,
        "price" =>  84,
        "status" =>  1,
        "visibility" =>  4,
        "type_id" =>  "simple",
        "mediaGalleryEntries"=> [{
          "mediaType"=> "image",
          "label"=> "hassel",
          "types" => ["base","small","thumbnail","swatch"],
          "position"=> 0,
          "disabled"=> false,
          "file"=> "path/to/image.jpeg",
          "content"=> {
            "base64EncodedData"=> "base64_encoded_image",
            "type"=> "image/jpeg",
            "name"=> "image_name"
        }
    }]
    }
```